# 'None' and 'No one'

Tags: pronouns, verb-agreement

Do we use a plural verb with 'none' and a singular verb with 'no one'?
We may say: None but the brave deserve accolades. But when we use 'no one', it is grammatically correct to say that 'No one deserves accolades but the brave'.

Answer (score 2):

***None*** but the brave deserve accolades.

*None* is a fused determiner that can take singular non-count nouns (*None of the meat was fresh*) and plural nouns (*None of the boys went*). *The brave* here  is understood as *brave people* where the head is the plural noun *people*; so plural *deserve* is fine.

***No one*** deserves accolades but the brave.

*No one* is a compound determiner whose nominal base/head is the singular *one* so it takes singular verb agreement, as in your example with the singular *deserves*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct to say *No one deserves accolades but the brave.*

In fact, saying this makes it sound a tad bit stricter, as if accolades were only and only for the brave